# Subquery in Where clause SQLKata

Tags: c#, subquery, where-clause, sqlkata

I try to pass subquery to where clause in SQLKata and compare it with 0 value.

In SQL it should be like this:

```
WHERE (SELECT count(id) FROM main.someTable) > 0
```

I try to reproduce it in SQLKata by this code:

```
var countSubQuery = 
    new Query("main.someTable")
        .SelectRaw("count(id)");

return query
    .Where("0", "<", countSubQuery);
```

But I get error message:

```
column \"'0'\" does not exist
```

How can I fix this? Maybe I should pass zero value by another way?

Answer (score 1):

I could solve my problem:

```
query = query
         .WhereSub(countSubQuery, ">", 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var countSubQuery = 
    new Query("main.someTable")
        .SelectRaw("count(id)");

return query
    .Where(Sql("0"), "<", countSubQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks for response.

In what namespace can I find `Sql`-method?
I can't find it in SQLKata

Comment: I tried to pass `new SqlResult().RawSql = "0"` but it didn't help